# The space before \DeclareMathOperator'ed operator

Tags: spacing, amsmath, math-operators

The code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator\rad{rad}

\begin{document}
The quotient $A/\rad A$ is hopefully semisimple
\end{document}
```

results in

[image]

and the spacing between the solidus and the `rad` is killing me. Is there a way to make operators get a more sensible spacing in that context?

Comment: Probably use `A/{\rad A}`

Comment: Well, yup, that does certainly work. I had something more automagical in mind :-) If one replaces the `/` by a `\mathbin/` it does get set symmetrically. Can one simply change the class of `/` in a document and nothing breaks?

Comment: I think that would break more than it will help. Perhaps better to make a `\quotient{A}{\rad A}` macro and have it appy `{...}` to the second argument.

Comment: the problem is not `\rad` it is `/`  it is `\mathord` like `x`  because 1/2 gets spaced like 1/2 not 1 / 2  so `A/\rad A`  is spaced like Ax\rad A` and gets a space before the `\mathop` `\rad`

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Knuth actually discusses this issue in the TeXbook. The thing is, while `/` is technically a binary operator, in traditional math typesetting, we don’t put spaces around it as for other binary operators. Therefore, in TeX, for lack of a better option, it was given the class “ordinary”. So `/\rad` gets interpreted as “ordinary + operator” and therefore receives an extra space, unfortunately. The best solution is indeed `A/{\rad A}`.

Comment: I have a few hundred of those, sadly.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez The “replace all” function in your editor is your friend.

Comment: @Gaussler While doing `A/\!\rad A` (or with the braces) is sensible, it's disputable whether it should be applied to `x/\log y`, depending on the font used and the slant of the slash. In the particular case, defining `\newcommand{\qrad}[1]{#1/\!\rad#1}` would be the best solution.

Answer (score 5):

You can define a slash that uses `\mathopen` so it does not have space before a `\mathop`. I would use a specfic command, but you can use `\mathcode"8000` to define `/` this way if you want

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator\rad{rad}
\mathchardef\origslash\mathcode`\/
\newcommand\mslash{\origslash\mathopen{}}


\begin{document}

$ 1 \mslash 2 $

$ 1 \mslash \rad x $

$ 1 \mslash \log y $

$ 1 \mslash (a+b) $

{\catcode`\/=\active\global\let/\mslash}
\mathcode`\/="8000


$ 2 / 2 $

$ 2 / \rad x $

$ 2 / \log y $

$ 2 / (a+b) $
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your idea is much more better and simpler.:)

Comment: @wipet you forgot to add "as always with latex" :-)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to `\DeclareMathSymbol{/}{\mathopen}{letters}{"3D}`? That doesn't require active characters and only changes spacing in combinations that are not really relevant for normal typesetting (like `/+`, `/=`, `/\left`, `\sin/`).

Comment: Do you see something LaTeX specific in your answer?

Comment: @HenriMenke easier but mathopen would change the space before / admitedly only for \mathop,  did consider that...

Comment: @wipet no not at all, I was just teasing

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But the only space change before `/` would be for Op-Open vs. Op-Ord, so in something like `\sin/` which I don't think occurs naturally anyway.

Comment: @HenriMenke yes I know. Perhaps I should add that as a possibility

Comment: @HenriMenke I disagree slightly. I would say that `\tan = \sin/\cos` is completely normal mathematical typesetting. But it’s unlikely to appear in the same text as `A/\rad A`.

Comment: @Gaussler but Henri's suggestion would keep `\sin/cos` with symmetric spacing (removing space on both sides) mine just removes space on the right, so arguaby would be less good for that case.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well, `\sin/2` could also appear in a math text. Anyway, how about something like `\newcommand\mslash{\mathclose{}\origslash\mathopen{}}`? Note also that there is notation like `X/\sim` (`X` mod an equivalence relation) to keep in mind. But personally, I would always put braces around `\sim` in this case.

Comment: @Gaussler again `\sin/2` here (and by default)  has space before / and not after, but using just mathopen would have symmetric (zero) space

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Hence my suggestion `\mathclose{}\origslash\mathopen{}`.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to do "replace all" in your editor, you can try following macros which redefines behavior of the `/` character in math mode:

```
\def\specslash{\mathchar`/\futurelet\next\specslashA}
\def\specslashA{\ifx\next\rad \mskip-\thinmuskip \fi}
{\catcode`/=13 \global\let/=\specslash}
\mathcode`\/="8000
```

Comment: This could get very technical once you start to use other operators than `\rad`, too. I think the only really usable solution would be one that checks if the next token has class “operator”. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: `\hbox{/}` will pick the glyph from the wrong font. Maybe better to use ``\mathchar`/``?

Comment: OK, using `\mathchar` is better. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might try the split fraction from `xfrac`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xfrac}

\DeclareMathOperator\rad{rad}

\begin{document}
The quotient $\sfrac{A}{\rad A}$ is hopefully semisimple
\end{document}
```

[image: Computer Modern font sample]